# In OpenLayers how do I prevent linestrings and polygons disappearing as I zoom out?

Tags: polygon, openlayers, style, zoom

I can see how to do this using a feature style function with 2 styles (similar to the Custom Polygon Styles example). One would be the normal linestring/polygon one and used at high enough zooms.

The second would show just the first coordinate as a point and used at low zooms. I already use style functions, but none have depended on resolution yet.

The cut-off point between the two styles would depend on how big the feature would appear at that zoom (i.e. on resolution, and its extent?).

This seems a standard thing that anyone would want, so is there a simpler way of doing it? If not, can you give me any guidance on how to set the cut-off point?

I have seen the issue addressed elsewhere, but the only answer seemed to be about [GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144278/how-to-prevent-small-polygon-wms-features-to-be-hidden-when-zoomed-out-geoserve), which I am not using.

Comment: A typical cutoff might be when the feature extent (calculated in pixels as the extent width or height divided by resolution) is smaller than the symbol used to represent a point.  Instead of first coordinate you might want to consider using the label points - `getCoordinateAt(0.5)` of a linestring or `getInteriorPoint()` of a polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for that advice. I have managed to get it working. I wanted to treat polygons and lines the same so, for the record, I used essentially:

```
if (maxPixels(feature, resolution) > pointRadiusInPixels) {
  // normal ol.style.Style
} else {
    new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({...})
      geometry: function(feature) {
        return new ol.geom.Point(ol.extent.getCenter(feature.getGeometry().getExtent()));
      };
    });
  }

function  maxPixels(feature, resolution) {
  var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
  return Math.max(extent[2]-extent[0], extent[3]-extent[1]) / resolution ;
}
```